# How do I create a lookup based diff across two worksheets in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, office365

I know that there are many other ways to do this, but for reasons, I'm stuck in Excel :D

I have a spreadsheet that lists IDs and descriptions. Each month, I take a snapshot of a set of data and stick it into Excel. Let's say Jan and Feb worksheets within the same workbook.

These values will not always be in the same order, so looking up the data based on the ID is vital.

```
January (Sheet 1)
A     B
ID    Desc
1     DingDong   
2     ClapClap
3     Hotdog
4     Rhythm of the feet

Feb (Sheet 2)
A     B
ID    Desc
1     Changed
2     ClapClap
4     uh oh!
3     Hotcats
```

I want to write a script, or formula, or whatever to **produce a list of every description that has changed between the two worksheets based on ID**.

So in this case, it would show

```
Changes
1    Changed
3    Hotcats
4    uh oh!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vlookup in an if statement formula like this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(D1,A1:B5,2,0)<>VLOOKUP(A1,D1:E5,2,0),"Diff","Same")
```

This example has your 2 lists in the same sheet at cols A & B and D & E and the formula in col G. Your ID is in the first col and the value in the second of each list, but you can link across worksheets and it will still be the same. You can use another formula in the next column to show the original value if needed.

Edit:

To work over 2 sheets, copy this formula down for each row of data you have:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1:B5,2,0)<>VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1:B5,2,0),"Diff","Same")
```

Tested to work, the cell with the formula results in the word Diff or Same depending on the result.

Comment: I think the syntax may be off there at the end.But this seems to work well for a single row. 

     `=IF(VLOOKUP(D1,A1:B5,2<>VLOOKUP(A1,D1:E5,2,0),"Same","Diff")`

However, I dont think it handles changes in the ID. For example, ID 2 may not always be in the same cell in both sheets. I updated the example to be more clear.